# Getting app search result from android market in code

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an android app in sdk version 2.2, in which there is a searcher. The searcher searches for apps in market for things like app name, or publisher name, package name etc. We then want to  show the list of app results in a our app (instead of in default market app) to let the user to select a particular app. Then the details page for that app will be launched in market app.
I found [android-market-api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api), but it is not working properly for following scenarios:

1. When I am giving my own androidID instead of "dead000beef.
2. Sometimes "dead000beef" is also giving problem.

Is there any properly working sample code using this api or is there any other way to fulfill my above requirements?